# Getting list length from caml query

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-object-model, ajax

I am currently trying to determine the length of a list that is located on my SharePoint site. I am using a Caml query to retrieve the items in my list, but I can not figure out how to get the length of the result. I am using the Client Object Model and javascript / Ajax / jquery etc...

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var currentweb = context.get_web();

    query.set_viewXml('<View>' +
                                '<Query>'+
                                    '<Where>'+
                                        '<IsNotNull>' +
                                            '<FieldRef Name="ID" />'+
                                        '</IsNotNull>' +
                                    '</Where>'+
                                '</Query>'+
                                '<ViewFields>'+
                                    '<FieldRef Name="Name"/>'+
                                '</ViewFields>'+
                            '</View>');


    var colList= currentweb.get_lists().getByTitle("MyList");

    this.docList= colList.getItems(query);
    context.load(this.docList);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

When the code runs context.ExecuteQuery() the console prints out this.

```
context.ExecuteQuery is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javaScript (and SilverLight) client object model doesn't implement `clientContext.ExecuteQuery` only the `ExecuteQueryAsync(successDelegate, failDelegate)`.

Comment: Sure it does. At least in SilverLight. I've used it before, and just checked to make sure I wasn't crazy. It's there. It works.

Comment: Obviously that is the case in javaScript though, seeing the above error that's thrown.

Comment: @rjcup3 Well the SilverLight has it, but only if running outside UI thread, so it's generally discouraged to use it. JavaScript doesn't even have it, which is probably a better approach

Comment: Why would you want to perform non-UI actions on the UI thread? I only use the UI thread for the UI... I do generally use the asynchronous model, but I have used  queries synchronously if they need to be executed in direct succession (ie: data from query A is used in query B, which returns data used in query C). It's just easier to keep them all in one function.